# Creating a New OneToOneField for Django Postgres App Using SQL Commands

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have an app with several django/python data models and associated postgres database tables.  In this case the important ones are `User` and `Feed`.

I need to create a one to one relationship between a column in my Feed model and items in my User model.  If I were starting the app from scratch I would simply define a `user` property in my `Feed` models as such:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Feed(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

Of course, being that my app is already functioning, I need to modify my database tables with SQL commands in accordance with my django/python data model changes.

My question is, what SQL commands do need to create a `OneToOneField`?  I've used the documentation here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html as a guide when doing SQL commands in the past.  But I'm concerned that I'm gonna screw something up when it comes to OneToOneFields.

The django `manage.py sqlall` command tells me that I need a column that looks like:

```
"user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Why not use a migration app?

Comment: That of course requires me to configure the library and learn their API.  I'm lazy, I want a one-time SQL command.  But based on the lackluster response to this question, I'm thinking I might have to learn a migration app.  Ive heard south is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all you out there with a similar problem... I ended up opting for the `south` migration library. (at some point I'd still like to learn SQL commands).  [Getting south to work was fairly straightforward](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model).

```
$ pip install south
$ cd [pathtoproject]
$ vim [project]/settings.py

# make sure the following is reflected
INSTALLED_APPS += ('south',) 

$ ./manage.py syncdb
$ ./manage.py convert_to_south [myapp]
$ vim [myapp]/models.py

# make the changes to the data models. 
# south has to be initialized before these changes occur

class Feed(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)


$ ./manage.py schemamigration [myapp] --auto
```